# ¿Cómo crear una animación del botón degradado brillante en FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, animación, gradient

Me gustaría crear un botón con una animación del botón degradado brillante (Como en el gif adjunto), pero sale todo mal. Lo único que hace el botón es que un color vaya a la izquierda y otro a la derecha haciendo que el degradado no se vea bien. lo que quiero hacer es que los colores vayan tras del otro de derecha a izquierda y  también que el boxShadow tenga el tono de los colores degradados. En el código solo puse 2 colores pero me gustaría agregar 4 máximo.

Así es como me gustaría que se viera el botón:

[image: animación del botón degradado brillante]

```
class _GlowingButtonWidgetState extends State<GlowingButtonWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Alignment> _centerLeftAnimation;
  late Animation<Alignment> _centerRightAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 4),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _centerLeftAnimation = Tween<Alignment>(
      begin: Alignment.centerRight,
      end: Alignment.centerLeft,
    ).animate(_controller);

    _centerRightAnimation = Tween<Alignment>(
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
      end: Alignment.centerRight,
    ).animate(_controller);

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        widget.onPressed();
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller,
            builder: (context, _) {
              return Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      widget.color1,
                      widget.color2,
                    ],
                    begin: _centerLeftAnimation.value,
                    end: _centerRightAnimation.value,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: widget.color1.withOpacity(0.6),
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 8,
                      offset: const Offset(-8, 0),
                    ),
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: widget.color2.withOpacity(0.6),
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 8,
                      offset: const Offset(8, 0),
                    ),
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: widget.color1.withOpacity(0.2),
                      spreadRadius: 8,
                      blurRadius: 16,
                      offset: const Offset(-8, 0),
                    ),
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: widget.color2.withOpacity(0.2),
                      spreadRadius: 8,
                      blurRadius: 16,
                      offset: const Offset(8, 0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      widget.text,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Así es como se ve actualmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class AnimatedColorButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AnimatedColorButton> createState() => _AnimatedColorButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedColorButtonState extends State<AnimatedColorButton> {
  final List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.purple
  ];
  int colorIndex = 0;

  Color get startColor => colors[colorIndex % colors.length];
  Color get endColor => colors[(colorIndex + 1) % colors.length];

  late Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        colorIndex++;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: endColor,
            blurRadius: 16,
            spreadRadius: 1,
          ),
          BoxShadow(color: startColor, blurRadius: 16, spreadRadius: 1),
        ],
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          // Duración de la animación para el cambio de color
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [startColor, endColor],
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
            // Bordes redondeados del botón en sí
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            
          ),
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Animated Button',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: animación color en el botón]

Comment: Muchas gracias!